# Regular expression to check if string has certain number of digits

Tags: java, regex

I have address information and some junk in my DB and I have to just check if the string has zip code I need to process that. Can you explain how to check if a string has a 5 digits present. For example,

```
String addr = 10100 Trinity Parkway, 5th Floor Stockton, CA 95219;
```

So it has to match this string as it is having 5 digit zip code. Any way to check using Java Regular Expression?

Update:

```
String addr = "10100 Trinity Parkway, 5th Floor Stockton, CA 95219"; 
String addressMatcher = "\\d{5}";
if(addr.matches(addressMatcher)){
System.out.println(addr);
}
```

Above is the code I am using after getting the answers but none of the regex matches and prints the addr. Am I doing anything wrong?
Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple expression is `".*\\d{5}$"`, which says that you want any character 0 or more times, then any digit 5 times, and then the end of the string. Note that this accounts for needing to escape the slash in the Java string.

If you may have more characters at the end of the string, then you can append `.*` to the expression to match those. However, that may end up matching number in addresses as well, so make sure your data is in a consistent, expected format.

Regular expressions may not be sufficient in this case, since not all 5-digit numbers are actually zip codes. As well, some zip codes may include additional numbers (usually following a `-` after the first five digits.)

Comment: Would that also match substrings of 123456789, e.g. in a sentence "my zip is 12345 and my phone number is 123456789" you might get more than 1 match?

Comment: It depends what you do with the regex. There are several options once you've created a Regex object.

Comment: @Neil yes, it would. It's not clear how OP is actually going to use the regex, though. Looking at his input string, he actually has 5 digits in the street address as well (even accounting for word boundaries.) As such, I gave the most straightforward version possible, and OP can use it and improve as needed.

Comment: @dlev good point - missed seeing that even with word boundaries it would also match the 10100 bit.

Comment: Regex not matching anything wrong, I have updated my question.

Comment: @Karthik You may need to specify a regular expression for the surrounding text as well. I've udpated my answer.

Comment: @dlev: Still its not matching even the given address in the question but matching others. Any Idea? Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Karthik I missed the `;` in the earlier string. Will that character always be there? Can you ignore it? Adding `.*` to the end of the expression will make it work, but you're better off figuring out what will be in your strings.

Comment: @dlev: semicolon wont be there anymore ".*\\d{5}.*" works perfectly. Thanks for your effort please update them in your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for:

(\w\s*)+,(\s*(\w\s*)*,)*\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*[1-9]{5}

This expression will match: 
1 - any words with any spaces followed by comma, 
2 - then optional repetitions of words separated by spaces followed by comma 
3 - at the end , it is ended with two characters words (the state code), followed by zip code which is 5 digits (non-zero digits)

I hope this help

[Edit] 
This expression will filter out numbers in the address that are not in the correct place to be zip code, like for example ( 10100) in your example